# Подключение open-uri выбивает ошибку при старте

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Помогите пожалуйста в решении задачи. Возможно я делал что то не так или может быть забыл что либо предустановить.

Взял код из учебника:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://pragprog.com') do |f|
  puts f.read.scan(/<img alt=".*?" src="(.*?)"/m).uniq[0,3]
end
```

выбивает ошибку:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:223:in
`open_loop': redirection forbidden: http://pragprog.com ->
https://pragprog.com/ (Runti meError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:149:in
`open_uri'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:688:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
        from ./lib/methods.rb:123:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Внимательно смотрим на описание ошибки. В нём скрыт ответ.

Comment: Джаву установить что ли ?

Comment: Я уже менял ссылку с http на https  и обратно. Не фиксится.

Comment: А если ещё внимательнее сравнить урлы редиректа?) Чтобы было проще - поставить урл с https и посмотреть куда с него пытается редиректить.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, сообщение об ошибке уже содержит в себе информацию о том, что же пошло не так. Измените протокол с http на https в урле.

```
require 'open-uri'

open('https://pragprog.com') do |f|
  puts f.read.scan(/<img alt=".*?" src="(.*?)"/m).uniq[0,3]
end
```